# PHP Invalid password even if valid

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords

I am trying to make a login system using php, mysql but even if I enter correct username and password combination, the site tells me that they are invalid.

What is the problem?

My code:

```
     <?php
    session_start();
      $error_msg = "";

      if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
          require_once('config.php');
          $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

          $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));
          $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password']));

          if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {
            $query = "SELECT user_id, username FROM users WHERE username = '$user_username' AND password = SHA('$user_password')";
            $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
              $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
              $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

              setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));    // expires in 30 days
              setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  // expires in 30 days
              $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/loggedin.php';
              header('Location: ' . $home_url);     
            }
            else {
              $error_msg = 'Invalid username and/or password.';  
            }
          }
          else {
            $error_msg = 'No empty fields allowed!';
          }
        }
      }

        echo '<a href="register.php">Click to register</a>';   
    ?>
<HTML>
<BODY>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <?php
        if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo '<p>' . $error_msg . '</p>';
        ?>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Login</legend>
          <label for="username"><font color="black">Username:</font></label>
          <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if (!empty($user_username)) echo $user_username; ?>" /><br />
          <label for="password"><font color="black">Password:</font></label>
          <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
      </form>


    <?php
      }
      else {
        // Successful
        echo('');
      }
    ?>  
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

You may wonder if I have the correct data in config.php.
Yes, I have the correct connection username, host, password, and db name, because I use the same file to the registration and it works perfectly.

Thanks,
Henrik

Comment: Try `echo $query;` and run that printed query in `phpMyAdmin` or `mysql` directly and see if it returns the user as it should.

Comment: How are you saving the password to the database on registration? Is the database field its size sufficient? In your query you use MySQL's SHA function.

Comment: registration: $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, activation, ip) VALUES ('$username', SHA('$password'), '$email', '$activation', '$ip')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

Comment: What's the `password` field type and length in mysql?

Comment: i tried to run the query in phpMyAdmin it returned 0.

Comment: password field type: varchar(30)

Comment: Please have a look at the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, the SHA-* algorithms are not appropriate to hash passwords, because they are ways too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need at least 40 CHAR/VARCHAR field for password to save it using mysql SHA function.
Also you can check `SELECT SHA('password')` straight in mysql editor to see if saved value in db is what you expect.